# How to incorporate missing metadata into SQL statement?

Tags: sql

I need to classify a field with 2100 unique values into about 50 different groups. The relationship between the groups and the unique values is not stored in the database.  My current approach is a gigantic case statement thusly:

```
Case
   When tbl.field1 in('val_0001', 'val_0002', ..., 'val_00nn') then 'Group 1'
   When tbl.field1 in('val_0101', 'val_0102', ..., 'val_01nn') then 'Group 2'
    .
    .
    .
   When tbl.field1 in('val_0m01', 'val_0m02', ..., 'val_0mnn') then 'Group m'
   else tbl.field1 
end as MyGroup
```

Is there a better approach when the needed metadata is not present within the database?

Comment: Create a temp table/table variable and join it in instead.  Or substring the values (get the '00' from val_0001, val_0002, etc) and use that instead if there is a logical progression to it.

Comment: Load the data into the database.  That seems like the logical solution, if this lookup is needed for multiple queries (or the same query run multiple times).

Comment: @Gordon - Yes, that would be the most appropriate approach, but the database is not mine and the list might require periodic maintenance.

Comment: @PaulAbbott - There is not a logical progression to the values, they were just my generic example.  I will research creating a temp table instead, that sounds promising.

Comment: The temp table would need to be recreated in every session. Temp tables are like local variables, they disappear when the session they were created in closes. I second @GordonLinoff's suggestion to just make this part of your persistent data.